# How to Customize RadRating tooltip for each Star

Tags: asp.net, telerik

My question is related to Customization of RadRating tooltip for each item. I am assinging Value to RadRating in a method. Actually I have to show 1 star for 2 values. e.g If my value is 6 than 3 stars should be selected and I have to use only 5 Stars. My code on server side for assinging value to RadRating is :

```
RadRatingCustomerUp.Value = (customer.Rating != null) ? Convert.ToDecimal(customer.Rating / 2) : 0;
```

While on markup it i as :

```
<telerik:RadRating ID="RadRatingCustomerUp" runat="server" Precision="Half" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                        ReadOnly="false">
                                    </telerik:RadRating>
```

Now how could I show tootip that comes on hover of rating stars equal to my value. If my value is 7 than 3.5 stars are selected and tooltip it shows is 3.5 but I want to show the tooltip according to my exact value (7) and if 2 stars are selected than tooltip must show 4 on hover

How Can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following client script will override the value that is displayed in the tooltip of the RadRating. You just need to place it on the page with the cusomized rating control.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var old_getItemValue = Telerik.Web.UI.RadRating.prototype._getItemValue;

        $telerik.$.extend(Telerik.Web.UI.RadRating.prototype, {
            _getItemValue: function (item, checkOverParts) {
                var oldValue = old_getItemValue.apply(this, arguments);
                return oldValue * 2;
            }
        });
    </script>
```